# How can I make my axios function reusable in other React/Typescript components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, refactoring, dry

I am copying/pasting the same code for making axios requests in multiple components like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get<IDownloads[]>(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/api/downloads`, {

        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        timeout: 5000,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setFaqs(response.data);
      })
      .catch((ex) => {
        const err = axios.isCancel(ex)
          ? 'Request cancelled'
          : ex.code === 'ECONNABORTED'
            ? 'A timeout has occurred'
            : ex.response.status === 404
              ? 'Resource not found'
              : 'An unexpected error has occurred';
        setError(err);
      });

  }, []);
```

Which works, but doesn't follow DRY.  I want to be able to reuse this code in other areas of my application but need to be able to change the .get<IDownloads[]>(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/api/downloads` to work in other areas. Like .get<ISomethingElse[]>(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/api/somethingElse`  I made a new component in attempt to do this

```
export default function useApiRequest<T>(url: string): { response: T | null; error: Error | null} {
   const [response, setResponse] = React.useState<T | null>(null);
   
    const [error, setError] = React.useState<Error | null>(null);
  
    React.useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async (): Promise<void> => {
       try {
           const res = await axios(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}${url}`);
           setResponse(res.data);
       } catch (error) {
           setError(error);
       }
    };
    fetchData();
}, [url]);
  
    return { response, error };
  };
```

and using it in this component like this:

```
interface IDownloads {
  db_id: number;
  file_description: string;
  file_name: string;
  developer_name: string;
  date_uploaded: string;
  file_url: string;
}

const defaultProps: IDownloads[] = [];

const DownloadCodeSamplesPage: React.FC = () => {

  const downloadQuery = useApiRequest<IDownloads[]>('/api/download');
 
  const [downloads, setDownloads]: [IDownloads[], (posts: IDownloads[]) => void] =
    React.useState(defaultProps);
```

In my return I am mapping through the downloads like so

```
                  downloads.map((download) => (
                    <tr key={download.db_id}>
                      <td>{download.file_description}</td>
                      <td>{download.file_name}</td>
                      <td>{download.developer_name}</td>
                      <td>{download.date_uploaded}</td>
```

When I run the program I am not receiving any data from the api call.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Duplication of State

Your hook looks great.  The issues are with how you are using it in your component.  **You don't need a local state for `downloads`** -- that's the point of the hook!  So kill that `React.useState` and wherever you were calling `setDownloads`.

You can access the `downloads` from the hook and replace it with an empty array if it's `null`.

```
const downloads = downloadQuery.response ?? [];
```

```
const DownloadCodeSamplesPage: React.FC = () => {
  const downloadQuery = useApiRequest<IDownloads[]>("/api/download");

  const downloads = downloadQuery.response ?? [];

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
      {downloads.map((download) => (
        <tr key={download.db_id}>
          <td>{download.file_description}</td>
          <td>{download.file_name}</td>
          <td>{download.developer_name}</td>
          <td>{download.date_uploaded}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

You might consider creating an [axios instance](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance) for your site that is preconfigured with the `baseUrl` and any other settings and use this everywhere in your app.